# NPM pulls corrupted packages from Verdaccio instance

Tags: node.js, npm, npmjs, sinopia

When I perform a basic `npm install` in an application I am attempting to set up a dev. environment for corrupted packages end up being pulled from my Verdaccio proxy instance.

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Set up package.json for my project including adding my dependencies,
   etc.
2. Set my local system to use my Verdaccio instance: `npm set
   registry [[Verdaccio Server URL]]:4873`.
3. Perform `npm install` within the directory I have the package.json in.

**Results**

I get a ton of output similar to the following:

```
npm http fetch GET 200 [[Proxy NPM Site]]/@angular%2fplatform-browser-dynamic/-/platform-browser-dynamic-5.2.11.tgz 6430ms
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/router@5.2.11 (sha512-NT8xYl7Vr3qPygisek3PlXqNROEjg48GXOEsDEc7c8lDBo3EB9Tf328fWJD0GbLtXZNhmmNNxwIe+qqPFFhFAA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for jquery@3.3.1 (sha512-Ubldcmxp5np52/ENotGxlLe6aGMvmF4R8S6tZjsP6Knsaxd/xp3Zrh50cG93lR6nPXyUFwzN3ZSOQI0wRJNdGg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for ng-bootstrap@1.6.3 (sha1-1B/UIVTAWTQiy4PEc6OCiqdSW/U=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
```

Note the URL encoded name of the package, in this case `@angular%2fplatform-browser-dynamic`. I do not get this when I set my proxy to be `https://registry.npmjs.org/`.

Of course, what I would like to do is be able to perform an `npm install` just as if I were connected to the official registry.

**Configuration and Log Files**

- [verdaccio-log.txt](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/files/2099142/verdaccio-log.txt)
- [npm-verbose-log.txt](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/files/2099143/npm-verbose-log.txt)
- [config.yaml.txt](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/files/2099144/config.yaml.txt)

**Additional Information**

- NPM Version: Latest - 6.1.0 but it happens with older versions.
- Node Version that Verdaccio is running on: 10.4.0
- Node Version that Client
  is running on: 10.4.0

**Environment**: Windows Server 2012 (SP2)

The server that Verdaccio is on is not behind a proxy.

Comment: facing the same error, but with [materialize css](https://materializecss.com) and [material-design-icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/)

Comment: @MatheusReis Try answer...

Comment: As reference https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/issues/756

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So after performing the following everything worked as intended:

```
rmdir /S /Q node_modules (or rm -rf node_modules on a *nix derivative OS)
del package-lock.json (or rm package-lock.json on a *nix derivative OS)
npm set registry [[My Verdaccio Instance's IP]]:4873
npm cache clean --force
npm install --force --verbose --no-bin-links
```

Comment: Removing the package-lock.json was what I needed to get npm back on track.

Comment: I tried all of the above, and none of it worked till I did the classic restart the computer.

Comment: Ive been about ready to slam my head against the wall for the past three hours. rm package-lock.json worked. Thank you so much

Comment: Removing the package-lock.json worked for me. I have a vague idea about what might be going underneath. In my case, it seemed to be something to do with checksum mismatching. The checksum and the version in the package-lock.json from the previous installation did not match with the package pulled from verdaccio (why I had the same version number for an updated package? -> It was a project related hack). Which is probably why it worked after deleting the package-lock.json

Answer (score 3):

I solved my issue with the following steps:

1. remove **package-lock.json**
2. run `npm cache clear --force`
3. run `npm cache verify`
4. run `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

If you roll back to NPM version 3, it will start working again. Publishing to Verdaccio with NPM@3 and then pulling with NPM@>=5 was causing this problem for me.

Comment: I've been having this issue for months and always skipped past this answer.  This is actually what fixed all of my issues.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a problem with your node/npm and not with Angular CLI.

I suggest you try to use

1. `npm cache clear --force`
2. `npm install`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had to turn off Verdaccio's cache

```
uplinks:
  npmjs:
    url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
    cache: false
```

Comment: IMHO doesn't this make the private repo less useful? Caching is what allows you to reduce traffic, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the package-lock.json. It solved my problem.